# XML schema restriction pattern for Allowing empty strings(Whitespace) and Applying Validation only for non empty strings

Tags: regex, xml, validation, xsd, pattern-matching

I need to restrict a tag in xsd as follows,

**1.** The tag value can be empty

**2.** When the tag value is not empty, then only alphabets and integers are allowed

I am able to do the validation for the 2nd point as 
    pattern **value="[A-Za-z0-9 ]{3}"**

But how to make the regex pattern allow whitespace?

Comment: Found the solution as ([A-Za-z0-9 ]{3})?   The question mark needs to be added for this purpose

Comment: Add an answer with the found solution and mark it as correct .. In order to make clear this topic :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

**value="\s|([A-Za-z0-9 ]{3})"**

It satisfies your requirement

1. The tag value can be empty
2. When the tag value is not empty, then only alphabets and integers are allowed